# Get key-value pair based on minimum value in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, min

I've tried Googling this, but could not find an answer with regard to a situation similar to this one. I have a dictionary in the following format:

```
    my_dict={'key1': ['some_data', 'some_more_data',6.0], 'key2': ['junk', 'some_more_junk',7.0], 'key3': ['something_good', 'good',1.0]}
```

How would I go about creating a subdictionary containing only the key-value pair with the smallest number at the end of the list? In other words, I'd want my output to be:

```
    sub_dict={'key3': ['something_good','good',1.0]}
```

Note the minimum value will always be at the end of the list, the other elements in the list are pertinent to the key.

Comment: May `sub_dict` has multiple pairs if they have same value at last of the list?

Answer (score 2):

Builtin `min` function has `key` keyword argument.
So you **don't need to sort**.

```py
my_dict = {'key1': ['some_data', 'some_more_data', 6.0],
           'key2': ['junk', 'some_more_junk', 7.0],
           'key3': ['something_good', 'good', 1.0],
           'key4': ['test', 'test', 1.0]}

min_value = min(my_dict.values(), key=lambda x: x[-1])[-1]
new_dict = {k: v for k, v in my_dict.items() if v[-1] == min_value}
print(new_dict)
```

output:

```py
{'key3': ['something_good', 'good', 1.0], 'key4': ['test', 'test', 1.0]}
```

Comment: An interesting alternative to `key=lambda x: x[-1]` is to use `key=itemgetter(-1)`.. `itemgetter()` is in the `operator` module. I like that you thought ahead about possible items with the same min value

Answer (score 1):

You can sort using a special sorting function that will get you the intended key - value pair from the dictionary as the first element:

```
sort_res = sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1][-1])
k,v = list(sort_res)[0]
sub_dict = {k:v}
```

`lambda kv: kv[1][-1]` returns the last element of the list and uses it for soring. Since it is operating on a pair of key and value there is `kv[1]` which corresponds to the value.

Sorting gives us ordered *pairs* of key and value from the dictionary by the last element of the list. Then it is enough to take the first one and recreate a dictionary.

*Warning*: should there be more values on the original list that have the minimal value then you are going to get only one, arbitrary item of this value.

In such a case you can pick all of the items from the resulting list instead of picking only the first value:

```
lsort_res = list(sort_res)
res_dict = {}
minv = lsort_res[0][1][-1]  # take the last element of the v list of the first k,v pair
for k,v in lsort_res:
   if v[-1] == minv:
       res_dict[k] = v
```

Comment: This doesn't work if there are more items in the dict with the same min_value.

Comment: This is a special case that OP did not mention. But I have added a solution to this issue as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> min_value = sorted(my_dict.values(), key=lambda x: x[-1])[0][-1]
>>> {key: value for key, value in my_dict.items() if value[-1] == min_value}
{'key3': ['something_good', 'good', 1.0]}
```

First get the `min_value` and the filter the dictionary in a way such that it gets all the key-value pairs which match the `min_value`.

This will get all such key-value pairs where the last value is `1.0`.

---

You can also use `min` to get the minimum value directly:

```
min_value = min(my_dict.values(), key=lambda x: x[-1])[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do in this way:

```
sub_dict={}
smallest = 999999
key=''
for k,v in my_dict.items():
  if v[-1] < smallest:
    smallest = v[-1]
    key = k
sub_dict[key] = my_dict[key]
```